# Converting PDO resultset array to string

Tags: php, html, resultset

I have a class that retrieves a result set from a database. The result is wrapped in arrays which are then stored as session variables as shown in the code

```
 $days = array();
  $amount = array();
  $commission = array();

foreach ($result as $row) {
         array_push($days,$row['sales_day']);
         array_push($amount,$row['sales_total']);
         array_push($commission,$row['sales_comm']);
     $_SESSION['days'] = $days;
     $_SESSION['amount'] = $amount;
     $_SESSION['commission'] = $commission;
```

I then attempt to display the data in HTML table as in this code:

```
<tr>
    <td><label><?php print_r($_SESSION['days']); ?></label></td>
    <td><label><?php print_r ($_SESSION['amount']); ?></label></td>
    <td><label><?php print_r($_SESSION['commission']); ?></label></td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that the output is something like: array[0] => 1. But I want only the values retrieved from the database to display and not the array indices.

Comment: If `print_r` shows that, it means that's what `$row['sales_day']` (and others) contained to begin with. You're gonna have to show more code than that.

Comment: `print_r` is intended to output the structure of data, not as a user friendly table output. You'll need to iterate the data to output the individual values, probably each in their own `<td>`, like done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8393034/5459839). NB: the use of session variables seems irrelevant to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I've considered that you need to save data in a part of your code and print them s**omewhere else**.

if at the first step you want to save all items into `$_SESSION` and then show them in next steps, use this code:

the first step:

```
$merged_data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $merged_data[] = array(
        'sales_day' => $row['sales_day'],
        'sales_total' => $row['sales_total'],
        'sales_comm' => $row['sales_comm']
    );
}
$_SESSION['merged_data'] = $merged_data;
```

the second step: (**somewhere else** in your code)

```
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['merged_data'] as $data) { ?>
    <td><label><?= $data['days']; ?></label></td>
    <td><label><?= $data['amount']; ?></label></td>
    <td><label><?= $data['commission']; ?></label></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sohiel. I used your code as is and it worked perfectly.  But note that the variables in $data are: sales_day, sales_amount, sales_comm. Thanks again. I am very grateful

Comment: @Zeekstem your welcome, you can select the answer as the accepted answer if it solved your problem